# Proper clopen subset of disconnected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

In Chapman Pugh's Real Analysis the definition of a disconnected set is that it has a proper clopen subset. I was trying to apply that to a simple example but got the following inconsistency:

The disconnected set $U=[a,b]\cup[c,d]\subset\mathbb R$ where $a<b<c<d$ should have a proper clopen subset. However, $\mathbb R$ has no clopen proper subsets and any proper subset of $U$ is also a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ which is a contradiction. Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is the thing: your subset has to be clopen _in $U$_. In general topology, there is no "absolute" notion of open/closedness, and you always talk about a set being clopen _in some space_. In the definition of disconnectedness, this space is $U$.

Comment: Does the book say "nonempty proper clopen subset?" Because the empty set is also clopen.

Comment: @MattSamuel actually in the textbook he defines a proper subset as being nonempty.

Comment: That's pretty bizarre to me, but it does resolve the problem.

Comment: Rather similar older question: [Let $X = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ be a metric space. Why is $[0,1]$ both open and closed?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1003063)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mistaking the idea of being "open in $U$" with "being open in $\Bbb{R}$".

Indeed, $[a,b]$ is open in $U$ with the subspace topology because if you choose any $e$ with $b<e<c$, then $[a,b]=U\cap(a-1,e)$. It is also closed in $U$ because $[a,b]$ closed in $\Bbb{R}$ and $[a,b]=U\cap[a,b]$.

Comment: Indeed, I think one of the biggest misconceptions people have with basic topology is the idea that a notion like "open" is a property of a set, when instead it's a relationship between a set and a space.

Answer (score 8):

$[a, b]$ is clopen *in* $U$, by the definition of subspace topology. It is closed because it's equal to $[a, b]\cap U$, and it's open because it's equal to $(a-1, \frac{b+c}{2})\cap U$.