# Why is $[0,1]$ an open subset of $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $X = [0,1]\cup[2,3]$

I have to show $[0,1]$ is both open and closed in $X$.

This question is also asked in this thread :

[Let $X = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ be a metric space. Why is $[0,1]$ both open and closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003063/let-x-0-1-cup-2-3-be-a-metric-space-why-is-0-1-both-open-and-close)

I understand why $[0,1]$ is closed, but am having trouble understanding why it is open.

From the answer in the previous thread, I understand that $[0,1]$ is open as it is the complement of $[2,3]$ which is closed.

But for the point $0$ in $[0,1]$ we can construct no open ball which lies in X. So then how is $[0,1]$ open in X?

Comment: Hint: What are the open balls of the subspace topology?

Comment: In general, the open & closed sets in the subspace are the intersections of open & closed sets in the containing space intersected with the subspace. Presumably the containing space above is the real line, so since $[0,1] = X \cap [0,1]$ it is closed in the subspace and since $[0,1] = X \cap (-1, {3 \over 2})$ we see that it is open in the subspace.

Answer (score 2):

$[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is an open ball *in $X$* (not in $\mathbb R$):

$$[0,\frac{1}{2}) = \{ x \in X : |x| < \frac{1}{2} \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot MichaelBurr and copper.hat.

The key was to think in terms of the relative metric for $X$ and not the metric used for $\mathbb{R}$. The relative metric restricts the definition of the metric for only those points which belong to $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. In this case, $[0,1/2)$ is also an open ball in [0,1] when X is the metric space under consideration.

Alternatively,as suggested by copper.hat, one may look at $[0,1]$ as $X\cap[0,1]$ where $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Also it can be seen as $X\cap(-1,3/2)$ where $(-1,3/2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.